# PowerShell find and enumerate properties found in nested JSON array

Tags: json, powershell

Given a JSON document like the one shown below, I want to get the value of `OctoConnectedServiceName` without explicitly specifying the index of parent object in the array of `tasks`.

```bsh
# Here is an example JSON document
$JSONText = @'
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "enabled": true,
            "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
            "inputs": {
                "workingDirectory": "",
                "failOnStderr": "false"
            },
            "task": {
                "versionSpec": "2.*",
                "definitionType": "task"
            }
        },
        {
            "environment": {},
            "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
            "inputs": {
                "OctoConnectedServiceName": "abc1234-1234-1234-1234-efg78910",
                "Space": "Spaces-1"
            },
            "task": {
                "versionSpec": "4.*",
                "definitionType": "task"
            }
        }
    ],
    "runsOn": [
        "Agent",
        "DeploymentGroup"
    ],
    "revision": 5,
    "createdOn": "2019-10-07T18:48:13.603Z",
    "modifiedOn": "2019-10-10T19:29:00.460Z",
    "comment": "",
    "version": {
        "major": 1,
        "minor": 0,
        "patch": 0,
        "isTest": false
    },
    "groups": [],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "aliases": [],
            "options": {},
            "properties": {},
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "helpMarkDown": "",
            "groupName": ""
        }
    ],
    "satisfies": [],
    "postJobExecution": {}
}
'@
$JSONText.GetType() 
# Is of type string

$JSON = $JSONText | ConvertFrom-Json
$JSON.GetType() 
# Is of type PSCustomObject.  This is the type of object served from Invoke-RestMethod
#  and this is what I want to get the value of 'OctoConnectedServiceName'

# Here is the solution that i'm currently using - not ideal
[regex]$regex = '"OctoConnectedServiceName":[^,]*' 
$regex.Matches(($JSONText | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10)) | % {$_.Value}
```

Ideally, I want the same results, but without needing to stringify the JSON and use regex.  The expected result via form searching the PSCustomObject would be...

`"OctoConnectedServiceName":  "abc1234-1234-1234-1234-efg78910"`

Comment: Can't you just access the property directly from the original object?  e.g. `$JSON.tasks.inputs.OctoConnectedServiceName`

Comment: @boxdog You could access it in a manner similar to that.

With my example JSON it would actually be...

`$JSON.tasks[1].inputs.OctoConnectedServiceName`

However, therein lies the issue...  

The OctoConnectedServiceName property could be in a task at a different index.  Being able to recursively search the document for the property and get its value, no matter where it is in the document, would be a very powerful and flexible solution.

Comment: I added multiple tasks with `OctoConnectedServiceName ` entries to your JSON and using the syntax I suggested I was able to get all of the values - PowerShell helpfully performs an implicit enumeration.